# BeautifulSoup `find_all` generator

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to turn `find_all` into a more memory efficient generator? For example:

Given:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
return soup.find_all('item')
```

I would like to instead use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
while True:
    yield soup.next_item_generator()
```

(assume proper handing of the final `StopIteration` exception)

There are some generators built in, but not to yield the next result in a find. `find` returns just the first item. With thousands of items, `find_all` sucks up a *lot* of memory. For 5792 items, I'm seeing a spike of just over 1GB of RAM.

I am well aware that there are more efficient parsers, such as lxml, that can accomplish this. Let's assume that there are other business constraints preventing me from using anything else.

How can I turn `find_all` into a generator to iterate through in a more *memory efficient* way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*There is no "find" generator in `BeautifulSoup`*, from what I know, but we can combine the use of [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) and [`.children` generator](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

Let's imagine we have this sample HTML:

```
<div>
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
</div>
```

from which we need to get the text of all `item` nodes.

We can use the `SoupStrainer` to parse only the `item` tags and then iterate over the `.children` generator and get the texts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

data = """
<div>
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
</div>"""

parse_only = SoupStrainer('item')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser", parse_only=parse_only)
for item in soup.children:
    print(item.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
```

In other words, the idea is to cut the tree down to the desired tags and use [one of the available generators](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#generators), like `.children`. You can also use one of these generators directly and manually filter the tag by name or other criteria inside the generator body, e.g. something like:

```
def generate_items(soup):
    for tag in soup.descendants:
        if tag.name == "item":
            yield tag.get_text()
```

The [`.descendants`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants) generates the children elements recursively, while `.children` would only consider direct children of a node.

Comment: Beautiful. Great way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest method is to use [find_next](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

def find_iter(tagname):
    tag = soup.find(tagname)
    while tag is not None:
        yield tag
        tag = tag.find_next(tagname)
```

Comment: `find_next()` is an interesting idea!

Comment: @alecxe. Another nice thing about it is that it allows starting from any point in the document.

Comment: Nice, looks like a drop-in replacement for the "find" generator to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#generators):

> I gave the generators PEP 8-compliant names, and transformed them into
>   properties:

```
childGenerator() -> children
nextGenerator() -> next_elements
nextSiblingGenerator() -> next_siblings
previousGenerator() -> previous_elements
previousSiblingGenerator() -> previous_siblings
recursiveChildGenerator() -> descendants
parentGenerator() -> parents
```

There is chapter in the Document named [Generators](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#generators), you can read it.

**SoupStrainer** will only parse the part of html, it can save memory, but it only exclude the irrelevant tag, if you html has thounds of tag you want, it will result same memory problem.