# .find() in BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to search an html document.  Is there a way to search the document for a table that contains certain keyword strings?  For instance, if I had the table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 'abc' </td>
    <td> 'other data' </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 'def' </td>
    <td> 'other data' </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> '123' </td>
    <td> 'other data' </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> '456' </td>
    <td> 'other data' </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in an html document that had many other tables, but this was the only one that contained the strings "abc", "def", and "456", is there a way to search for this table?

A thought I had was to use a for loop to search all tables and rows and data, but that seems like an unnecessary number of steps (the document is very large).  Is there a way to form the question using BeautifulSoup, like (obviously this won't work but maybe it gives an idea of what I want to be able to write):

```
.find('table', string=('abc'), string=('def'), string=re.compile('456'))
```

edit: Yes, the table needs all of those strings. The html file also contains other tables which may contain any of those strings, but only 1 table has all 3 together.  And yes, I would only be looking for strings within the  tags (which might be 'text' instead of 'string', I'm not sure of the difference).

Comment: Please post your example HTML as part of a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for posting the html example.  There are a couple things that would clarify your question: does the table need to contain *all* of those strings, or *any*?  Can those strings be contained only in <td> tags, or anywhere in the table?

Comment: Yes, the table needs all of those strings.  And yes, I would only be looking for strings within the <td> tags (which might be 'text' instead of 'string', I'm not sure of the difference).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to [pass a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to `soup.find()`.  That function has to take one and only one argument (a `bs4.element.Tag` object), and its purpose is to return only True or False: True if the table matches the criteria you set out.

If you'd like to test different strings, you can start with a function that takes two parameters and use `functools.partial()` to get it down to one:

```
from functools import partial

def _table_contains_strs(tag, strings):
    """Return True if `tag` has <td> tags that contain `strings`."""
    if tag.name != 'table':
        return False
    tds = tag.find_all('td')
    if not tds:
        return False
    test = {s: False for s in strings}
    for tag in tds:
        for s in strings:
            if s in tag:
                test[s] = True
        if all(test.values()):
            # You can return early (without full iteration)
            # if all strings already matched.
            return True
    return False

def _make_single_arg_function(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return partial(_table_contains_strs, *args, **kwargs)

table_contains_strs = _make_single_arg_function(
    _table_contains_strs,
    strings=('abc', 'def', '456')
)
```

Now `table_contains_strs` is a function that takes a single argument, a `Tag`.

Here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Add some text to other tags to make sure you're
# finding only in <td>s
html = """\
<table>
    <th>field1</th>
    <th>field2</th>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>other data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>other data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>other data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>other data</td>
  </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.find(table_contains_strs)
# Should return the table above
```

---

Note: I can't say this would scale exceptionally well because it's using a nested for-loop to check for *each* string in *each* `<td>` tag.  But hopefully it gets the job done.  It might not be a great idea to just use `.text` because this will capture other nested tags as well, which you specified you didn't want.  Another optimization would be to make a lazy [generator version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41372225/7954504) of `find_all()`.

Comment: Thanks! The example worked, but as you said it did not scale well to the  amount of data I am trying to process.  It did give me some ideas to try though.

Comment: Are you able to share the actual web page url?  @BuckBacot

Comment: It's a loop that reads all of the annual reports on the sec.gov EDGAR database.  The problem is that the documents are not all formatted the same (different words and phrasing, but also different html formats).  I was trying to get a catch-all way to find specific tables by finding the tables that contain certain keywords.